# Sleep doesnt work but Hibernate works

Tags: windows-10, sleep, hibernate, usb-3, powercfg

I have windows 10 creators update. when I put my windows to sleep it turns on again after 1 or 2 seconds. (this problem didn't occur with creators update, but happened of some windows self updates probably. also **no** device is recently  added to the pc)

I checked through powercfg lastwake:

`Wake History Count - 1
Wake History [0]
  Wake Source Count - 1
  Wake Source [0]
    Type: Device
    Instance Path: PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_A12F&SUBSYS_86941043&REV_31\3&11583659&0&A0
    Friendly Name: Intel(R) USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller - 1.0 (Microsoft)
    Description: USB xHCI Compliant Host Controller
    Manufacturer: Generic USB xHCI Host Controller`

Note that I got PS2 keyboard and that's the only keyboard I have. so disconnecting that is not a solution. Also I didn't have this problem for 10 years since i used this keyboard.

This problem happends even if i got no connection to USB ports.

Weird enough, when I enable hibernate through powercfg, windows hibernate successfully and does not wake up itself.

I don't want hibernate enabled, because its slower. also power outage is not problem for me.

Also I disable all wakearmed devices, except mouse. but still got the problem.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Check the Power and sleep settings, try change the "on a battery power, PC goes to sleep after" setting to 2 mins and verify whether the PC goes to sleep after 2 mins or not.
the reason is you have 2 settings one for screen and another for sleep, the screen setting will switch off the screen after the time specified in the screen settings. The PC will goes to sleep after number of minutes specified in the Sleep settings probably your PC is only switching off the screen.